# Formatted output using printf() adding unwanted space/lines - C Programming

Tags: c, string, formatting, printf, string-formatting

This is the function with which I am having the issue. Primarily the printf statement at the end. I am relatively new to C, however I feel this is an unusual outcome. Any help would be most appreciated!

```
void frequencies(char htmlDoc[]) {
    tags(htmlDoc, 0);
    int ndx;
    //  struct tagCounter *pCursor = tagCounters[0];
    int size = 1;
    char *name;
    for (ndx = 0; ndx < tagCntSize; ndx++) {
        name = &(tagCounters[ndx]->tagName[0]);
        while (*(name + 1) != '\0') {
            size++;
            name++;
        }
    name = &(tagCounters[ndx]->tagName[0]);
    char thisName[size];
    int index;
    int thisCount = tagCounters[ndx]->tagCount;
    for (index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        thisName[index] = *name;
        name++;
    }
    printf("%s\t%i\n", thisName, thisCount);
    }
}
```

This is the resulting output:

```
img
�   1
img
    1
img
    1
img
    1
img
    1
img
    1
Ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char thisName[size];
```

After this do

```
memset(thisName,0,sizeof(thisName));
```

`%s` expects a null terminated string. Or after exiting the loop

```
thisName[size] = '\0';
```

Edits:

The array size should be large enough to hold a null termination for a string.

```
char thisName[size + 1];
```

Comment: Awesome that makes a lot of sense. I added the terminate char at end and it did not fix the problem. like I said I am new to C, i have java experience but despite their closeness they are like comparing lions to zebras. I am unfamiliar with memset, I will look into it.

Comment: @GeorgeG. The problem is you don't have space to store the null character make your array size as `size+1`

Comment: This did not alleviate the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: memset solved another problem I hit later on! plus adding the null pointer plus a little research/ better understanding of C and programming in general fixed my program overall. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

char *name, *ptr;

ptr = name = &(tagCounters[ndx]->tagName[0]);

while (*ptr != '\0')
    ptr++;

size = ptr - name;

before printf:

thisName[size] = '\0';

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you could do arithmetic with ptrs like that. Is the formatting issue because my string has white space?

Comment: Your  variable "thisName" is not with the string terminator (NULL), so is printing garbage on the screen.